# Why does relative path keep changing and how to prevent it?

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I use Java to create a folder "myCoolFolder" like this:

`Files.createDirectories(Path.of("MyCoolFolder"));`

This is relative path. What surprises me is this - the folder sometimes is created one level deeper or higher in the folder structure and I do not know the reason for that suspicious behavior. Maybe it depends on the way I run the project and what it thinks is the 'working directory', but I'm not really sure about that. How can I make sure it is always the same folder?

Answer (score 2):

A relative pathname is resolved relative to the working directory of the process that resolves it.

If it is resolving to different locations at different times then either the process (application) is started with (in) a different working directory, or (possibly) it is changing its working directory.  (There isn't a portable way for a Java process to change its own working directory.)

> How can I make sure it is always the same folder?

Either make sure that you launch your Java application with the same (correct) working directory, or use an absolute pathname for the folder.

Comment: This is what I though is going on. Unfortunately, I should not use absolute path and launching it with the same working directory every time is not satisfying solution, because everybody working on this code is required to be extra careful.

Comment: Well maybe you could use a path relative to (say) the user's home directory?

Comment: Ideally, I want it to be relative to the project's main folder.